# Overflow with absolute/relative positioning layout

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

for quite some time I'm fiddling around with a specific layout matter that I'm obviously approaching the wrong way.

Here is the approach broken down to its basic components:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="stretched">
    <div class="header">SOME HEADER</div>
    <div class="someControls">
        <input type="button" value="click me"/>
        <input type="button" value="no me"/>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        some text...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

with the following css:

```
.stretched {
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 30px auto 20px;
    background-color: green;
}

.inner {
    margin:10px;
    background-color: red;   
    overflow: auto;        
}
```

​What I'm trying to do is having the `stretched` div utilizing all available vertical viewport space (minus a few pixels above and below for header and footer) and being centered horizontally with a fixed with.

This seems to work pretty well. The problem is that the `overflow: auto;` property is not applied to the `inner` content as I want it to. When `some text...` gets longer, the `inner` div overlaps my container and shows no scrollbars.

Here's the Fiddle: [fiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/365/)

I want to avoid having scrollbars on the page body and instead having the overflow managed by scrollbars inside the `inner` div, thus making `stretched` always entirely visible.

I could apply the same trick with `position: absolute; top: 0; ...` to the `inner` div as well, but then I have to specify the height of `header` + `someControls` explicitly, which I want to avoid, because it is different on all my pages.

This is how it works like I want it to (except for the part `top: 40px;`): [fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/5gyt5/6/)

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for well-structured question and trying yourself.

Comment: Is IE7 support required?

Comment: Not necessarily. Would be nice, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with pure CSS (..that works in all common browsers).

Here's an approach using the [old Flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) spec: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/xRr7e/

Unfortunately, it only [works in](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) WebKit browsers/Firefox.

It's time to use a few lines of JavaScript for this layout..

Answer (score 0):

Hey why are define position absolute in your style sheet

replace this one

```
    .stretched {

    width: 250px;
    margin: 30px auto 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Live demo  http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Rpdr9/366/

Updated js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Rpdr9/368/

Comment: Thanks! Had to make my question more precise, would be great if you'd check out the second fiddle I added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
position: absolute;
```

and add

```
border: 10px solid green;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/367/

EDIT: If you dont like huge border, you can change the border-size to 1px.

```
border: 1px solid green;
```

Even this works.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to avoid scrollbars on the page body, seems like I have to make my question more specific. The `stretched` div should alway be entirely visible, and overflow should be handled by scrollbars in the `inner` div.

Comment: Yes, but without the fixed height. Please check out the other fiddle I added to my question.